# How to select the rows with maximum timestamp for each month?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, history-tables

How can I select the maximum timestamp for each month?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(timestamp) ... GROUP BY month ...`

Comment: Or `SELECT ... WHERE cust_id = 756 and end_date is null`

Comment: Your question is Really short on useful information

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please, in future, don't use screengrabs to show data. Include the text of the data in your question indented four spaces.

Comment: I`m sorry, I should have explained the situations well. I will edit it later.

Comment: I suggest you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Query will do the job.

```sql
SELECT 
YEAR(START_DATE), 
MONTH(START_DATE), 
MAX(IFNULL(END_DATE, '9999-12-31 23:59:59'))
GROUP BY YEAR(START_DATE), MONTH(START_DATE)
```

Comment: Why START_DATE, and not END_DATE, or, for example, a middle between them?

Comment: From the example data in the question I have concluded that the month is defined via START_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, fairly efficiently given the correct indexes.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(start_date) month_ending,
       MAX(end_date) max_end_date
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(start_date)
```

Comment: I`m sorry, I mean I want to select the rows that have the latest record for each month. I thought i could use the "LAST_DAY" but it only returns the last day of each month